# How to report a bug on a different issue?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting, apport

When using the apport system to report Ubuntu bugs, I type in this in Terminal and press enter:

```
ubuntu-bug
```

That then launches up a window which looks like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/2kmwFUp]

And as what I am reporting has nothing to do with any of those packages listed (well it may do but I don't really know and wouldn't want to pick the wrong one), I select the option called "Other problem", which then gives me this message:

[image: http://imgur.com/YJUme3W]

I would have thought that what it would be would be the equivalent of selecting the "I don't know" for packages option in LaunchPad. But apparently not, so why is this that that option just gets me an error? Why is that option even there if I cannot continue by selecting it? Is this a bug? Or is it just their way of telling you that you cannot report other problems there...?

Comment: Please see this answer.http://askubuntu.com/a/137915/146791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intention is that you would run `ubuntu-bug <package>`. Given that this isn't clear to you so you had the question, I'd say that there is a separate bug in Apport here, which is that the error message isn't being helpful to you.

Comment: It seems that there are many bug reports about Apport on LaunchPad. So I hope that they will get this sorted somehow, even if it is by changing the error message or something. But thank you for your information.