# How to report kernel issues

Tags: kernel, bug-reporting

This is a followup to this other thread: [USB ports not working all of a sudden](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671282/usb-ports-not-working-all-of-a-sudden)

I'm working on an Acer Aspire E 15, with the OS being Ubuntu Studio 14.04.

I noticed that the last kernel version:

```
Linux version 3.13.0-63-lowlatency (buildd@lgw01-18) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #103-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 14 22:23:32 UTC 2015
```

This one is giving certain issues to my computer (USB ports don't work). The last kernel version that always works is this one:

```
Linux version 3.13.0-61-generic (buildd@lgw01-50) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 29 11:21:34 UTC 2015
```

I guess there is a sort of incompatibility with Acer Aspire E 15 computers, and I'd like to report this problem because of course I hope that the next kernel versions to be released will solve it. Also, I'm worried about what could happen in case this kernel version (3.13.0-61, the last working one) gets purged being old, maybe via and accidental `autoremove`.

I checked this other thread: [How to report a bug on a different issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571397/how-to-report-a-bug-on-a-different-issue). It suggests that I should use `ubuntu-bug`, but I don't know what option to click on to report this kind of issue.

Comment: Kernel bugs need to be reported to https://bugzilla.kernel.org/ BUT this question is not about Ubuntu so "ubuntu-bug" would be inapproprate (making this question also off topic ;) ) Better place to ask would be http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I thought the kernel was part of the Ubuntu system, that's why

Comment: @Rinzwind why is the **procedure** how to report a bug against an **Ubuntu kernel** off topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I upgraded to `Ubuntu Studio 15.04`. Once done the upgrade, I didn't have this issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

- Are you sure `3.13.0-63-generic` is not working?

  You have tried `3.13.0-63-lowlatency` (**`-lowlatency`**) which is different then **`-generic`**
- Please,read this [Filing Kernel Bug reports (Ubuntu Wiki)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs).

  > The submitter should provide as much information as possible in the
  >   bug description:
  >
  > 1. The majority of kernel bug are hardware specific so be sure to note what hardware/device is being used.
  > 2. Document any known steps to reproduce the bug.
  > 3. Also note whether the bug exists in previous kernel versions of Ubuntu or if it's a regression from previous kernel versions.
  > 4. **Finally, it's critical to also make sure to test the latest development Ubuntu kernel version as well as [the latest upstream
  >      mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelMainlineBuilds).**

  Before trying last upstream one, try `linux-generic-lts-vivid` which is from Ubuntu 15.04 (last release). It's already in Trusty repository:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
  ```

Comment: I tried both `generic` and `lowlatency` kernels, and I see that there is no difference for what concerns this issue: the kernel will or won't work wether it is `generic` or `lowlatency`, with no difference. Also, I tried `linux-generic-lts-vivid`, which if I start will give me a mesmerizing grey screen in which I see waves that gradually fill the entire screen in a unique bright grey pattern. Of course I already uninstalled it. I'll now follow those information you indicated to try the upstream kernel, and then to report the issue.