# video problem with kernel 5.13.0-28 on asus tuf laptop

Tags: boot, 20.04, video

Kernel 5.13.0-28 update causes video problems - flashing white/noisy screen. No problems when I revert to 5.11.46 install. There are multiple reports of this problem on the internet. When will this be resolved?
I have used linux for ~20 years and have been using the KUBUNTU variant for 10+ years. Every upgrade seems to present more problems - what is going on??
Ron Springer

Comment: Keep booting with the older kernel. In the next kernel update it'll be solved, probably.

Comment: What are your hardware specs?  What video card are you using?  From experience, NVIDIA drivers that you install from NVIDIA themselves do not contain the DKMS drivers that will carry over into the next kernel upgrade.  Where the drivers in the Ubuntu sources do install with DKMS and will carry over.

Comment: See [How to report kernel issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673700/how-to-report-kernel-issues)